# TableViewCell showing last item in array repeatedly

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I created an array that is filled from a JSON file. When I try to fill the table view with the array's items, it shows the last record repeatedly even though `indexPath.row` is returning correctly.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return leagueStandingsModelArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTeam", for: indexPath)

        let team = self.leagueStandingsModelArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = String(team.teamId)
        print(team.teamName)
        print(indexPath.row)

        return cell
    }
```

On my debug window, this is the result I am getting:

There are my array items printed

```
1 -- Santos -- 32

2 -- Palmeiras -- 28

3 -- Flamengo -- 24

4 -- Atletico-MG -- 24
```

And this is the return I get from these two lines below

```
print(team.teamName)

print(indexPath.row)

Atletico-MG

0

Atletico-MG

1

Atletico-MG

2

Atletico-MG

3
```

Should be printing the first four teams and not the fourth four times.

Full Code

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class LeagueOverviewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
let leagueModel = LeagueIdModel()
var leagueParams = LeagueParametersModel()
var leagueStandingsModelArray = [LeagueStandingsModel]()

var urls = URLs()

@IBOutlet weak var standingsTableView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return leagueStandingsModelArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTeam", for: indexPath)

    let team = self.leagueStandingsModelArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = String(team.teamId)
    print(leagueStandingsModelArray[0].teamName)
    print(leagueStandingsModelArray[1].teamName)
    print(leagueStandingsModelArray[2].teamName)

    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getLeagueIdJSON(country: leagueParams.country, season: leagueParams.season)


    standingsTableView.delegate = self
    standingsTableView.dataSource = self
}

//GET THE JSON FILE TO RETRIEVE LEAGUE ID USING COUNTRY AND SEASON AS PARAMETERS
func getLeagueIdJSON (country: String, season: Int) {

    let headers = Headers().getHeaders()
    let url = urls.getLeagueUrlByCountryAndSeason(country: leagueParams.country, season: leagueParams.season)

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let leagueJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            self.getLeagueId(json: leagueJSON, country: self.leagueParams.country, season: self.leagueParams.season)
            self.getLeagueStandings(leagueId: self.leagueModel.leagueId)

        }
    }
}


//GET LEAGUE_ID FROM JSON FILE RETRIEVED
func getLeagueId(json: JSON, country: String, season: Int) {

    var leagueId = 0

    if country == "gb" {

        for league in json["api"]["leagues"].arrayValue {
            if league["name"].stringValue == "Premier League" {
                leagueId = league["league_id"].intValue
            }
        }
    }
    else if country == "br" {

        for league in json["api"]["leagues"].arrayValue {
            if league["name"].stringValue == "Serie A" {
                leagueId = league["league_id"].intValue
            }
        }
    }

    leagueModel.leagueId = leagueId
}

//GET LEAGUE STANDINGS FROM A LEAGUE ID (TOP 4)
func getLeagueStandings (leagueId: Int) {

    let headers = Headers().getHeaders()
    let url = urls.getLeagueStandingsUrl(leagueId: leagueId)
    let leagueStandingsModel = LeagueStandingsModel()
    var counter = 0

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let standingsJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            for standings in standingsJSON["api"]["standings"][counter].arrayValue {
                if counter <= 3 {
                    leagueStandingsModel.teamId = standings["team_id"].intValue
                    leagueStandingsModel.rank = standings["rank"].intValue
                    leagueStandingsModel.teamName = standings["teamName"].stringValue
                    leagueStandingsModel.points = standings["points"].intValue
                    leagueStandingsModel.matchesPlayed = standings["all"]["matchsPlayed"].intValue
                    leagueStandingsModel.win = standings["all"]["win"].intValue
                    leagueStandingsModel.draw = standings["all"]["draw"].intValue
                    leagueStandingsModel.lose = standings["all"]["lose"].intValue
                    leagueStandingsModel.goalsFor = standings["all"]["goalsFor"].intValue
                    leagueStandingsModel.goalsAgainst = standings["all"]["goalsAgainst"].intValue

                    self.leagueStandingsModelArray.append(leagueStandingsModel)

                    let standings = String(self.leagueStandingsModelArray[counter].rank) + " -- " +
                        self.leagueStandingsModelArray[counter].teamName + " -- " +
                        String(self.leagueStandingsModelArray[counter].points)

                    print(standings)

                    counter += 1
                }
            }
        }
        self.standingsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: print `leagueStandingsModelArray` inside cellForRow and check that it is filled correctly.

Comment: you are printing `team.teamName` and setting `team.teamId`, as @JamesP mentioned this seems to be inconsistent dataSource

Comment: @wootage it isn't the problem here. Doesn't matter what item i am printing from the array. Problem is it is printing always the last index.

Comment: sorry @JamesP what do you mean?

Comment: `print(self.leagueStandingsModelArray)` and show us the result
Can you show the `Team`

Comment: That's it @wootage: [Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel]
[Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel]
[Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel]
[Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel, Foot24.LeagueStandingsModel]

Comment: and what if you replace `print(team.teamName)` with `print(team.tteamId)`.
`cellForRow` seems fine, the problem should be somewhere else (more likely in the Model or the array itself)

Comment: @wootage On the function that I fill the array. After getting all the infos from the json, I print it to see if it has been filled properly, and always looks ok.  

1 -- Santos -- 32
2 -- Palmeiras -- 28
3 -- Flamengo -- 24
4 -- Atletico-MG -- 24

I am able to retrieve the top 4 results normally

Comment: You'll have to show more code where you create or modify the array. From what you've shown the array only contains `Atletico-MG` 4 times.

Comment: I will edit with the function I populate my array. But look this: 1 -- Santos -- 32

2 -- Palmeiras -- 28

3 -- Flamengo -- 24

4 -- Atletico-MG -- 24.

These infos I got from my array. When I use my array out cellForRow it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reusing `let leagueStandingsModel = LeagueStandingsModel()` create new object right before populating it:

```
if counter <= 3 {
var leagueStandingsModel = LeagueStandingsModel()
leagueStandingsModel.teamId = standings["team_id"].intValue
...
```